# How do I get my Code to work with nested if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans

I am creating a Interactive Story in Java. I am using Netbeans and Jswing to do all the GUI. I have an issue when nesting another if statement inside it doesn't allow the parameter...

```
if("Open Locker".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
     jLabel2.setText("You open your locker and tap your textbooks and they appear in your inventory. The warning bell rings.");
     jLabel3.setText("You remember your next class is World History...");

     if("Go to World History".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
          jLabel2.setText("You walk down the hallway realizing that you still have 45 minutes until");
          jLabel3.setText("class starts. You arrive in class and sit in your desk.");
     }
 }
 else {
     jLabel3.setText("You cannot do that right now.");
 }
```

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXyvl.jpg)

I can type in open locker and it works but when I type in go to world history it doesn't work it says you cannot do this right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need keep track of last input. Lets take variable `isLockedOpened` to do that

```
boolean isLockedOpened=false;
```

Now if locker is open set isLockedOpened=true. Next time when user inputs "Go to World History" then check input and isLockedOpened variable. Your code looks something like this:

```
if("Open Locker".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
     //set locker opened
     isLockedOpened=true;
     jLabel2.setText("You open your locker and tap your textbooks and they appear in your inventory. The warning bell rings.");
     jLabel3.setText("You remember your next class is World History...");
 }else if("Go to World History".equalsIgnoreCase(input) && isLockedOpened=true) {
          jLabel2.setText("You walk down the hallway realizing that you still have 45 minutes until");
          jLabel3.setText("class starts. You arrive in class and sit in your desk.");
 }
 else {
     jLabel3.setText("You cannot do that right now.");
     //isLockedOpened=false;//you can set this to true or false but understand what will happen in both case.
 }
```

Hope this will provide you little hint !!!

Comment: I think that the OP wants a nested `if`, look at the title of the question. You can also read the text and it makes more sense.

Comment: For some reason it will not allow isLockedOpen to be turned to true in the if statement so it says that I cannot go to world history... Otherwise it works great and thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I can type in open locker and it works but when I type in go to world history it doesn't work it says you cannot do this right now

This happens because your `input` hasn't been changed. To get into the first option you need to type `Open Locker`, then for the second you need to type `Go to World History`, but you already typed something in.

What you need to do is ask for another input after you go into the first `if` statement:

```
if("Open Locker".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
     jLabel2.setText("You open your locker and tap your textbooks and they appear in your inventory. The warning bell rings.");
     jLabel3.setText("You remember your next class is World History...");

     //ask for input

     if("Go to World History".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
          jLabel2.setText("You walk down the hallway realizing that you still have 45 minutes until");
          jLabel3.setText("class starts. You arrive in class and sit in your desk.");
     }
}
```